# MIME Attachment Names containing Extended Characters Fails

Tags: c#, .net, email, mime, attachment

While working on a project that emails files with international filenames, I've come across an unusual issue. if I attach with a US-ASCII filename only, I can get better than 200 characters long without errors.

If I include an extended character, it encodes in UTF-8 and the length before it gets funky is very small (< 40 characters). To define funky.. here's an example filename after it goes bad:

```
=utf-8BSU5GT1JNw4FUSUNBX0ltcGFjdF9Bc3Nl
```

it looks like UTF8 encoded string with a UTF-8 decoding instruction or a mime boundary... not sure which.

Has anyone seen this before -- and what are the rules / limitations of filenames -- I tried emailing the file by hand through outlook and it handles it, so I don't think it is a MIME specific limitation.

Sample code:

```
class Program
{
    private const string DOMAIN = "foobar.com";
    private const string SMTPHOST = "mail." + DOMAIN;
    private const string FROM = "chadwick.posey@" + DOMAIN;
    private const string TO = FROM;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(FROM, TO, "Subject", "Body");

        string path = Path.GetTempPath();
        string name = "AAAAAA_AAAAAAAAAAAA_AAAAAAA_AAAA - IIIIIII CCCCCCCCCC DD IIIIIIÁIIII_20111018_091327.pptx";

        File.WriteAllText(path + "\\" + name, "blah");
        Attachment att = new Attachment(path + "\\" + name, new ContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"));

        msg.Attachments.Add(att);

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(SMTPHOST, 25);
        client.Send(msg);
    }
}
```

I've tried (so far) -- setting the encoding for the attachment.NameEncoding to UTF8 and UTF32, neither worked. Setting the ContentDisposition.FileName on the attachment fails because it is not using US-ASCII characters only.

Any suggestions on how to get it to include the full filename with the accent / extended characters in tact?

Thanks
Chadwick

Comment: Have you tried Unicode encoding {iso-8859-1}?

Comment: John: Yes... I tried unicode as well... it seems more to do with the length of the string when it includes the special characters than anything else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emaling attachments with long names and accents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654853/emaling-attachments-with-long-names-and-accents)

Answer (score 1):

There is a hotfix from microsoft that seems to have done the trick for me. 
[Check http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2402064](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2402064) 
On that page, there is a download link that will get you what you need. 
Just install the correct version, depending on your system.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
Attachment att = new Attachment(@"c:\path to file\somename.txt",    
System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);

//this itself should work.
att.Name = "история-болезни.doc";  // non-english filename

//if the above line doesn't make it work, try this.
att.Name = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(att.Name, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

[How to set the attatchment file name with chinese characters in C# SmtpClient programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397332/how-to-set-the-attatchment-file-name-with-chinese-characters-in-c-sharp-smtpclie/4397875#4397875)

Comment: After further review, the actual problem seems to stem from the length of the filename more than just the fact that it contains a few international characters.  If the encoded filename ends up wrapping more than one line, the .NET framework seems to encode the encoded filename and ends up corrupting the whole mess.  I've submitted it as a bug here: [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/696372/filename-encoding-error-when-encoding-utf-8-and-encoded-name-exceeds-the-length-of-a-single-mime-header-line#details), along with a modified version of the above.